# MySQL select n rows in between range

Tags: mysql, graph, line, range, between

Say I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID| Value
1 | 98
2 | 56
3 | 37
4 | 100
5 | 96
6 | 23
```

...and I only want to select four rows. However, the rows need to be representative of the set (it will be displayed as a line graph), and so I want, in this case, something like this:

```
ID| Value
1 | 98
2 | 56
4 | 100
6 | 23
```

Ie., a range of at most n (in this case four) results, including the minimum and maximum, with each result "spaced" as equally as possible from the rest.

Is what I'm asking for too much for MySQL, and if so, which other means would you recommend? I'd very much like to avoid selecting every single row, and then filtering some out using PHP.

Thanks a lot

Fela

Comment: Yeah, it's *a little bit* too much for MySQL.

Comment: Okay, but bear in mind the result set, after, say, a few months, will consist of thousands / tens of thousands of rows. The rows get added every 20 minutes by a cron job (long story).

Comment: You should probably have another cron job that runs every night (for example), calculates this stripped dataset and stores it somewhere.

Comment: You're into functions, there's not really a way to do it in a select statement. Though, saying that I guess you could take the min, max, mode and median... and start hoping that it gives you what you want.

Comment: I like the overnight cron job idea, but on the other hand, that wouldn't really support real time updates (which are sort-of required in this case).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but you don't want to do it.

You can pull the minimum (`SELECT MIN()`) and the maximum (`SELECT MAX()`), you can determine how many results are in a set (`SELECT COUNT()`). With the count, you can select specific rows in the result set (`SELECT ... LIMIT 2,1`). And then you could `UNION` all of these together. But it's going to be a pretty horrendous SQL statement, and it's really, really, not something that you want to use SQL for.

Far better that you pull all the results in question, perhaps ordered appropriately, and filter your results at a different level.

Comment: Alright then. I wrote a quick PHP implementation. I'm getting all (literally, SELECT * FROM table) the results, processing them with PHP (as the actual wanted data isn't in the MySQL results themselves), and filtering them out *after* they've been processed. It seems to work well enough.